# How do I sort a group of cards on changing a v-select?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have this v-select:

```
<v-select v-on:change="handleSort" v-model="sorting" label="Difficulty" class="ml-9" style="width: 15%;" outlined :items="orderNames" />
```

I want it to edit this group of cards:

```
        <v-flex md4 class="pa-6" v-for="lesson in lessons" :key="lesson">
           <v-card :href="lesson.link" class="card-container">
            <v-list-item three-line>
              <v-list-item-content>
                <div class="text-overline mb-2">
                  <v-row>
                    <span class="pl-3">{{lesson.level}}</span>
                    <v-spacer />
                    <span class="pr-3">{{lesson.time}} minute read</span>
                  </v-row>
                </div>
                <v-list-item-title class="text-h5 mb-1">
                  {{lesson.title}}
                </v-list-item-title>
                <v-list-item-subtitle>
                  {{lesson.description}}
                </v-list-item-subtitle>
              </v-list-item-content>
            </v-list-item>
            <v-card-actions>
              <v-btn v-if="lesson.link != null" :href="lesson.link" rounded depressed>
                Learn
                <v-icon class="pl-2">mdi-bank</v-icon>
              </v-btn>
              <v-btn v-if="lesson.yturl != null" :href="lesson.yturl" rounded depressed>
                <v-avatar>
                  <v-icon>mdi-youtube</v-icon>
                </v-avatar>
              </v-btn>
              <v-spacer />
            </v-card-actions>
          </v-card>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
```

Here is my script:

```js
export default {
  name: "LessonHub",
  data () {
    return {
      orderNames: ["Difficulty", "Time"],
      lessons: [],
      levels: [
        "Beginner",
        "Intermediate",
        "Advanced"
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    handleSort: function(selection) {
      switch(selection) {
        case "Difficulty":
          this.difficultySort();
          break;
        case "Time":
          this.timeSort();
          break;
      };
    },
    difficultySort: function() {
      var lessonList;
      for (level in this.levels) {
        for (lesson in this.lessons) {
          if (lesson.level.includes(level)) {
            lessonList.push(lesson);
          };
        };
      };
      this.lessons = lessonList;
    },
    timeSort: function() {
      var sorted = false;
      var lessonList;
      while (!sorted) {
        sorted = true;
        for (let i = 0; i < this.lessons.length; i++) {
          if (this.lessons[i].time > this.lessons[i+1].time) {
            var temp = this.lessons[i];
            this.lessons[i] = this.lessons[i+1];
            this.lessons[i+1] = temp;
          };
        };
      };
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    fetch("http://localhost:3000/lessons")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => this.lessons = data)
      .catch(err => console.log(err.message))
  }
};
```

**END GOAL:** I'd like the order of the cards to be switched when the v-select is changed, but my current attempts are not working.

**Current attempt:** To try to make `this.lessons` change, which should update the card order, I think. I've not seen any other questions like this, so I'm struggling to find documentation and/or examples to learn from.

**My attempt functions as follows:**
`handleSort()` calls the appropriate function (either `difficultySort()` or `timeSort()`), which should then edit `this.lessons`, which is defined in `data()` and edited in `mounted()`. This should then change the order of the `v-card` components, into the order that the user selected.

I don't know what `difficultySort()` is, but `timeSort()` is a bubble sort.

P.S. I am aware that this code is not very good, so I would gladly accept improvements in other areas of the code. However, my main issue at the moment is the one that I described above: how to reorder the list of cards when the `v-select` element contents are changed.

Comment: In this case it would be more logical to work with a computed instead of calling a method. Since you want your dataset to be based on a state of an variable. if you have an example of the data then i think we can further help you.

Comment: @TengjuChi here is an example:
```json
{
      "id": 1,
      "title": "Cyrillic Alphabet",
      "description": "Learn to read and write in the Rusyn variant of the Cyrillic alphabet",
      "time": 5,
      "level": "Beginner",
      "link": "http://localhost:8080/#/cyrillic-alphabet"
    },
```